# Determine expected value for continuous random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, continuous-data, moments

[image]

I know that $E[X^n]$ is found by $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^\infty{x^nf_x(x)dx}$$  
I simplified this to $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^\infty{ \frac{x^{\frac{v}{2}-1+n}e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}{\displaystyle\int_{0}^\infty{{x^{\frac{v}{2}-1}e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}}dx} dx }$$

But I don't know how to proceed, since i shouldn't solve the denominator.

Comment: Check what is gamma ditribution.

Comment: This question is a special case of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104241/moment-generating-function-of-a-distribution/368519#368519 (found by searching our site for "Gamma moment").  One doesn't need to integrate by parts at all, as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198595/expected-value-of-gamma-distribution/198621#198621 (found with the same search): the answer is a simple matter of dividing one constant by another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}E[X^n]& = \frac1{c_V}\int_0^\infty x^{n+v/2-1}\exp(-\frac{x}2) \, dx\\
&=\frac1{c_V}\left[\left.-2x^{n+v/2-1}\exp\left(-\frac{x}2 \right)\right|_0^\infty\right.\\&\left.+2(n+v/2-1)\int_0^\infty x^{(n-1)+v/2-1}\exp(-\frac{x}2) \, dx\right]\\
&=\frac{2(n+\frac{v}{2}-1)}{c_v}\int_0^\infty x^{(n-1)+v/2-1}\exp(-\frac{x}2) \, dx\\
&=2\left(n+\frac{v}2-1\right)E[X^{n-1}]\end{align}

I will leave the simplification as an exercise.